# How to run goals in aggregate pom after all of the child poms in maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, multi-module

I have two child projects that generate jar files. I also have an aggregate pom.xml to build them in the package phase, which works. I now would like to have a goal that runs after the child projects have been packaged to generate a dockerfile using the dockerfile-maven-plugin from spotify.

Is it possible to configure the aggregate pom with the dockerfile plugin in such a way that it will run only when the jars are fully built?

Comment: What about having a third module for the docker build?

Answer (score 2):

The simple thing is to have a multi module build which looks like this:

```
+-- pom.xml (root)
+--- child1
!       +-- pom.xml
+--- child2
!       +-- pom.xml
+--- aggregate-child
        +-- pom.xml
```

In the `aggregate-child` you define all the childs you would like to package as dependencies and in that you can also define the docker-maven-plugin to create the image.

Based on that structure you can call Maven from the root via `mvn clean package`.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. Is `pom.xml` a file in `aggregate-file` subfolder?

Comment: yes it is sorry wasn't accurate enough. Updated answer.